# Implementing Profiling using tracking keys in Tridion

Tags: content-delivery, profiling, tracking

I'm trying POC on implementing profiling and personalisation using DD4T. Using following code to increment the tracking key.

`WAIPage Waipage = new WAIPage(pageId, Context.ApplicationInstance.Conext);
TrackingKeys tk = new TrackingKeys(Waipage.User);
tk.IncrementKey("keyname"); tk.ExecuteUpdate();`

The User table is getting updated every time i load page but it's always coming with the value -1 for **presentation_id**. Also tracking key does not getting increamented in the tracking_keys table. And a cookie is getting set with name **Wai_-1** and it's having value **user_id=0** always.

I have gone through all the articles related to implementing profiling but I could not figure out what i'm missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the issue the host value in the cd_wai config was having http:// when i removed it, everything worked fine..